# Consequences of 'escape-time 0' tmux setting?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, tmux

I find that when running (neo)vim inside `tmux`, the escape-key is delayed. This is fixed by putting

```
set -sg escape-time 0
```

in my `.tmux.conf`. Presumably, this disables the possibility of using ESC as the "meta" key. Assuming that I always work with keyboards that have an Alt key to act as "meta", I'm wondering what potentially undesirable consequences that setting might entail.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Setting `escape-time` to zero interferes with tmux recognizing function-keys.  Its [manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) says

> **`escape-time`** `time`
>   
>   Set the time in milliseconds for which tmux waits after an escape is input to determine if it is part of a function or meta key sequences. The default is 500 milliseconds.

The term "function key" applies to anything that has that format (including pageup, used in scrolling by tmux, and cursor-keys).  500 milliseconds may be excessive if you never work remotely.  20 milliseconds is workable for local connections.  The analogous [`ESCDELAY`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT) in ncurses defaults to 1000 milliseconds; only a very small fraction of users find it necessary to change that.

Comment: hmm... arrow keys and pageup seem to work fine in tmux, even with escape-time set to 0

Comment: The documentation refers to key bindings handled by tmux (not the applications running inside tmux).

Comment: @AntoineCotten Could you expand on that? I thought that `Meta` sent nothing until it was paired with a non-function key, at which point it would send the escape and the key at "the same time" (less delay than any reasonable polling period, assuming it polls instead of using interrupts or something.) I followed my gut and never set the escape timeout below 10, mostly because I expected it to cause issues if the default was so high.

Comment: The behavior of *Meta* depends upon the terminal.  `tmux` doesn't have any control over that, but does know about xterm's special keys (in a table).  Meta for an ordinary key in xterm does something (look for `eightBitInput` in the manual).  For other terminals, it may do something, but usually is undocumented.

Comment: @JohnP @ThomasDickey I previously commented that settings `escape-time` to 0 interfered with _Meta_ commands in my terminal emulator. I would like to make a correction, this was only true because the macOS terminal uses `Esc` as the _Meta_ key. There is no issue when using a different key like _Alt_. Apologies for the misleading (deleted) comment.